# How to implement download video in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, download

i've developed laravel MVC web app that has a downloaded video in a Download page so When ever i click on download button it should get me the video downloaded, but instead it opens in a new tab in my browser

here is my code:

Controller download function:

```
 


  public function download($file_name) {
    $file_path = public_path('download/'.$file_name);

    return response()->download($file_path);

  }
```

Download button :

`<a href="/downloads/videp.mp4">Download</a>`

Comment: How do you define your route?

Comment: here it is :

Route::get('downloads', function()
{
  return view('downloads');

});

Route::get('/downloads/{file}', 'DownloadsController@download');